# How to find distance between numbers in a finite set that loops?

Tags: sequences-and-series, graph-theory

If we take a finite set of numbers and make them cycle at a specific threshold. For example with 5 as the threshold:

$1 \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 4 \rightarrow 5 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow etc...$

How can we find the distance between any 2 elements, considering that they form a cycle? So on that example:

$distance(1, 1) = 0$

$distance(1, 2) = 1$

$distance(1, 3) = 2$

$distance(1, 4) = 2$

$distance(1, 5) = 1$

Sorry for the messy explanation. I lack formal math education, and I'm just trying to figure out an code algorithm for a side project I'm developing. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let d  = $|a-b|$, the absolute value of the difference between them. Then the distance is the smaller of $d$ and $5-d$.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is this: if the threshold is $n$, then for $a \le b$:
$$
d(a, b) = \left\{
\begin{array}{l{\quad}l}
b - a &\mbox{if $b - a\le n/2$}\\
a + n - b &\mbox{if $b - a > n/2$}
\end{array} \right.
$$

and for $a > b$, $d(a, b) = d(b, a)$.

I.e., in the case when $a \le b$, you go up from $a$ to $b$ unless going up from $b$ to $a + n$ would be shorter.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is easier to do when using modulo, let the threshold be $n$:

$$
distance(a, b) = |((b – a + n / 2) mod n – n) mod n ± n / 2|
$$

*(± is dependent on the [programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215318/difference-between-modulus-implementation-in-python-vs-java) used, such as using addition in Java, C+, and Haxe or subtraction in Python, Ruby, and Symbolab. If $n$ is set to 360, this formula is also used for [angle distance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75587465/15389297).)*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).